# Why @SequenceGenerator has a name?

Tags: java, hibernate

The javadoc says

> A unique generator name that can be
>   referenced by one or more classes to
>   be the generator for primary key
>   values

But its annotation that is put on top of @Entity, so I don't understand the reasoning.

Can I use in @Entity @SequenceGenerator defined in other @Entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that multiple entities might want to share a key space.

For example if you have two entities `Foo` and `Bar` you'd want to avoid having both a `Foo` with id 1 and a `Bar` with id 1. You'd do that by specifying the same `name` for their `@SequenceGenerator` annotations.

Comment: what do you mean by key space? can you give a code example? you mean two @Enitites in one class?

Comment: No. I mean that the range of keys is shared by two separate entities. I.e. if an entity of type `A` has the key value `1` then no entity of type `B` will ever use that key value.

Comment: so you mean two fields in a @Entity?

Comment: NO! I'm talking about two separate classes, *each one* with a `@Entity` annotation **and** a `@SequenceGenerator` annotation.

Comment: so why you need a name? you could create "anonymous" SequenceGenerator and use it without name. As key space do you mean a Java package?

Comment: No, the key space is the range of values that the id property can take: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

Comment: I just saw that in some project every @Entity has annotation @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_TABLE", allocationSize = 1)- the name is always the same and it does not leak to other @Enities.

Answer (score 0):

You when using generator in @GeneratedValue annotation refer it by name. This is why the name is used. Sequence generator could be declared inside GeneratedValue annotation, but they decided otherwise. It gives you the possibility to use same Generator on multiple fields, or even share them between entities. When you not use this feature, it is of course some overhead for you.

Comment: I just saw that in some project every @Entity has annotation @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_TABLE", allocationSize = 1)- the name is always the same and it does not leak to other @Enities.